# Angular JS with dynamic donut chart

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dynamic, charts

I need guidance to update the donut chart dynamically using angular.
On my page 4 numbers of buttons present, when I clicked on 1st button then donut chart show 25% complete, when I clicked on 2nd button then it show 50% complete same like when I clicked on last button it shows 100% complete.

I didn't find good example

All button working in synchronous manner.

As when page loaded only one button is enabled and rest of the disabled.
after click on 1st button next button means 2nd one is enabled. That activity I already done.

Just need the chart and its update.

Comment: Can you show the code you already did?

Comment: https://github.com/aryanisml/DevOpsTesting  button enabled disabled is done only confused in which chart is suitable in this case, need to dynamically update the chart percentage